# KendoUI Data source Template

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-template

I write a template for my kendoUI DataSource like this:

```
<script id="SmallGalleryTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">



           <div style="width: 30%; float:left; margin-left: 55px; margin-bottom: 5%; margin-right: 8%">
                    <h4 class="p2">#= Name =</h4>
                    <figure>
                        <a href=ProductDetail.aspx?id=#= ID #>
                            <img class="img-border" src="images/Product/#= img #"/></a>
                    </figure>
                    <div class="box">
                        <div class="padding">
                            <a href=ProductDetail.aspx?id=#= ID #>Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>

    </script>
```

and I have :

```
  <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            var template = kendo.template($("#SmallGalleryTemplate").html());

            var datas = function () {

                var objects = [];
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "./Product.aspx/ProductGetAll",
                    data: {},
                    async: false,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:
                        function (response) {

                            for (var i = 0; i < response.d.length; i++) {

                                objects.push({ 'ID': response.d[i].PRODUCT_ID, 'img': response.d[i].PRODUCT_PHOTO_PATH, 'Name': response.d[i].PRODUCT_NAME });

                            }
                        },

                });
                return objects;
            };


            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: datas(),

                change: function () {
                    $("#SmallGalleryInner").html(kendo.render(template, this.view()));
                }
            });


            dataSource.read();


        });

    </script>
```

but it does not work and give me an error :

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Invalid template

what is the problem?

NOTE:ProductGetAll() method give me a list of data.

Comment: Please provide data of "objects".  If you provide sample data this will be easy for us to solve this issue. In your console write JSON.stringify(objects) and post result here.

Answer (score 1):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
<script id="SmallGalleryTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
            <div style="width: 30%; float:left; margin-left: 55px; margin-bottom: 5%; margin-right: 8%">
                     <h4 class="p2">#= Name #</h4>
                      <figure>
                        <a href=ProductDetail.aspx?id=#= ID #>
                            <img class="img-border" src="images/Product/#= img #"/></a>
                      </figure>
                      <div class="box">
                        <div class="padding">
                            <a href=ProductDetail.aspx?id=#= ID #>Read more</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
            </div>
    </script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {

            myobjects = new Array();
            for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

                var test = new Object();
                test.ID = i;
                test.img = "img" + i;
                test.Name = "name" + i;
                myobjects.push(test);
            }



            template = kendo.template($("#SmallGalleryTemplate").html());

            var dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                data: myobjects,

                change: function () {

                    $("#SmallGalleryInner").html(kendo.render(template, myobjects));

                }
            });


            dataSource.read();


        });

    </script>
```

Error in below code snippet.

```
<h4 class="p2">#= Name =</h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is closing the reference to `Name` in your template. You wrote:

```
<h4 class="p2">#= Name =</h4>
```

(close it using `=`) and it should be:

```
<h4 class="p2">#= Name #</h4>
```

(closing it with a `#`).